# Samsung S7 Media Queries

Tags: css, media-queries, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to use these media queries for S7 and it's not working
any other recommendations?

```
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {

/* Style */ 

}
```

Comment: Don't use specific devices mediaqueries, you'll have headaches. The answer below is fine

Answer (score 12):

I use this and haven't had a problem yet. Add all of this to your .css sheet

```css
/*
      Based on:
      1. http://stephen.io/mediaqueries
      2. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
    */

    /* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 6 in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 6 in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 414px) 
    and (max-device-width : 736px) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 6 Plus in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 414px) 
    and (max-device-width : 736px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 6 Plus in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 414px) 
    and (max-device-width : 736px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 568px) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 568px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 568px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
      
    }

    /* 
      iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
      It's noteworthy that these media queries are also the same for iPod Touch generations 1-4.
    */

    /* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 2G-4S in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
      
    }

    /* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 320px) 
    and (max-device-width : 480px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
      
    }

    /* iPad in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px)  {
      
    }

    /* iPad in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) {
      
    }

    /* iPad in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) {
      
    }

    /* Galaxy S3 portrait and landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S3 portrait */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S3 landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S4 portrait and landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S4 portrait */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S4 landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 320px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S5 portrait and landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S5 portrait */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {

    }

    /* Galaxy S5 landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* HTC One portrait and landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) {

    }

    /* HTC One portrait */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {

    }

    /* HTC One landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 360px) 
      and (device-height: 640px) 
      and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /*
      iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries
      If you're looking to target only 3rd and 4th generation Retina iPads 
      (or tablets with similar resolution) to add @2x graphics,
      or other features for the tablet's Retina display, use the following media queries.
    */

    /* Retina iPad in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      
    }

    /* Retina iPad in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      
    }

    /* Retina iPad in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
      
    }

    /*
      iPad 1 & 2 Media Queries
      If you're looking to supply different graphics or choose different typography 
      for the lower resolution iPad display, the media queries below will work 
      like a charm in your responsive design!
    */

    /* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      
    }

    /* iPad 1 & 2 in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      
    }

    /* iPad 1 & 2 in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      
    }

    /* iPad mini in portrait & landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      
    }

    /* iPad mini in landscape */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : landscape)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

    }

    /* iPad mini in portrait */
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 768px) 
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
    and (orientation : portrait)
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
      
    }

    /* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait and landscape */
    @media
      (min-device-width: 800px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1280px) {

    }

    /* Galaxy Tab 10.1 portrait */
    @media 
      (max-device-width: 800px) 
      and (orientation: portrait) { 

    }

    /* Galaxy Tab 10.1 landscape */
    @media 
      (max-device-width: 1280px) 
      and (orientation: landscape) { 

    }

    /* Asus Nexus 7 portrait and landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 601px) 
      and (device-height: 906px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
      and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) {

    }

    /* Asus Nexus 7 portrait */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 601px) 
      and (device-height: 906px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
      and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {

    }

    /* Asus Nexus 7 landscape */
    @media screen 
      and (device-width: 601px) 
      and (device-height: 906px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.331) 
      and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.332) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait and landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 800px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 7" portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 800px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {
        
    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 7" landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 800px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1280px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait and landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" portrait */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
      and (orientation: portrait) {
        
    }

    /* Kindle Fire HD 8.9" landscape */
    @media only screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) 
      and (orientation: landscape) {

    }

    /* Laptops non-retina screens */
    @media screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
        
    }

    /* Laptops retina screens */
    @media screen 
      and (min-device-width: 1200px) 
      and (max-device-width: 1600px) 
      and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
      and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
        
    }

    /* Apple Watch */
    @media
      (max-device-width: 42mm)
      and (min-device-width: 38mm) { 

    }

    /* Moto 360 Watch */
    @media 
      (max-device-width: 218px)
      and (max-device-height: 281px) { 

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys!

Comment: It does not answer the question. The OP asked about Samsung Galaxy S7

Comment: the media query css I posted covers that and considering this was answered over a month ago with no more questions from the original poster, I would say that it worked

Comment: I agree with Bastien. There is no s7 in your answer. It only goes up to s5

Comment: https://mydevice.io/devices/ shows that CSS width and height are `360x640` pixels and the pixel ratio is 4 i.e. `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3`

Answer (score 6):

Probably late to the party but, this is what I use for S7 and S8

```
/*Galaxy S7 and S8 */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 360px) and (max-device-width : 640px){


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your `<head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will tell the code to look at the actual pixel width of the devices viewport instead of the resolution value.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same problem just now.
After some testing on my device I've found that a **device-pixel-ratio of 3** is what targets my **Galaxy S7**.

Additionally,
I've found that the address bar is 75px tall if you wanna line something up with the fold.

This was in the **Chrome browser**.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked

```
/* samsung s7 portrait */
@media 
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3)
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi)and max-width:640px){

}

/* samsung s7 landscape*/
@media 
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) 
    and (min-resolution: 192dpi){

}
```

Comment: When asking/answering a question, have a look at the yellow block next to your input fields. It shows you how to format your text. Please edit your answer and format the code appropriately.